# SAS: convert a character variable to numeric, keep all 0's if the input has some fields with only 0's

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Objective: convert a character variable to numeric with proc sql in sas

Conditions:

- The input variable has x lenght
- must keep all 0's in each position
- THERE ARE SOME FIELDS OF ONLY 0'S

Ex:

The table has one variable with the following:

```
'00000000'
'00000000'
'00000001'
'20170617'
'20151201'
```

The expected output is one variable with:

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000001
20170617
20151201
```

I tried:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE AAA AS
SELECT input(field,z8.) as field_new
FROM input_table
QUIT;
```

But I get this undesired result:

```
0
0
0
00000001
20170617
20151201
```

Comment: Is the goal removing the quotes? If so, try the TRANSLATE() function.

Comment: I don't understand the question. There is no difference between the number 0 and the number 0000.  If you need to keep them different then leave them as character strings.

Comment: `Z8.` is a `FORMAT`, not in `INFORMAT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between the number 0 and the number 000.  If you want your numbers to print with leading zeros then attach the Z format to the variable.

Let's make an example dataset with a character variable.

```
data have ;
  length str $8 ;
  input str @@;
cards;
0 00000000 1 00000001 20170617 20151201
;
```

So to convert the string into a number use the `INPUT()` function.  Use the `FORMAT` statement to attach a format to control how it prints.

```
data want ;
 set have;
 num = input(str,F8.);
 format num z8.;
run;
```

Or in SQL syntax.

```
proc sql ;
create table want as
  select
    str
  , input(str,F8.) as num format=z8.
  from have
;
quit;
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Mr, this works, this is what I was trying to learn. Thank you.